# lightning:dataTable not available in Version 41.0 yet(Winter '18)

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, datatable, winter18

I was trying to use the lightning:dataTable in my Winter '18 preview enabled sandbox with Version 41.0(shown in snapshot)

[image]

But unfortunately it fails to identify the base lightning component(lightning:dataTable) in my component markup. Is there something i need to do before i start using it in my component?

Comment: What do you mean by fails to identify? It doesn't compile?

Comment: @MartinLezer it compiles, but when i add the component to my layout in app builder, it throws an error.

Comment: Yes I just tested it too. My guess is that as long as the new version is not officially launched, they block this component rendering. Also, there is no documentation yet and there must be some required attributes.

Comment: @MartinLezer Thanks Martin. As you pointed out, there's no much documentation available either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works fine for me in [Winter 18 pre-release org](https://www.salesforce.com/form/signup/prerelease-winter18.jsp) (gs0 instance).

```
<lightning:datatable columns="{!v.columns}" data="{!v.data}" keyField="Id"/>
```

Renders in App Builder and when on record detail page in Lightning Experience.

Make sure you are spelling the component with lowercase "datatable" perhaps?  Doubly verify the data you are binding to the component matches expected format per https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.210.0.lightning.meta/lightning/aura_compref_lightning_datatable.htm

Comment: Wow they finally released the documentation of the new components ! Nice !